# What was Skynet's intended purpose?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet

The question is very simple:  Why was Skynet made in the first place?  What was it for?  Why did people think we needed a Skynet?

Comment: Why is there research into AI going on in the real world?  Skynet's self-awareness might be fantastic by the standards of our current achievements, but the pursuit of Skynet itself is not.

Comment: @Praxis - I'm not saying AI is a bad idea, nor am I saying that Skynet was an inherently bad idea.  I'm just curious as to what purpose Skynet's designers had for making it.  Although they probably should have looked into Asimov's Three Laws.  :)

Comment: You misunderstand my comment. I'm saying that AI research is going on right now (and has been for seceral decades) in the real world. The reasons for pursuing Skynet in the fictional world are more or less the same reasons why AI is being researched in the real world.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting my usage of the word "fantastic".  It is not being used as a judgement.  The last sentence of my original comment to you means: *Skynet's self-awareness is extraordinary by the standards of our current achievements, but the pursuit of Skynet itself is not*.

Comment: @Praxis - no, I understood what you meant by "fantastic", I.e., like a fantasy, amazing, etc. But I did misunderstand your first comment - I thought you were assuming that I was inherently opposed to the idea of developing AI or something like Skynet.  I would be against building Skynet as it existed in the Terminator series, because it would kill us all, but something like Skynet wouldn't be so bad, if we avoided the murdery parts.

Comment: The original purpose of SkyNet was to optimize the placement of products on supermarket shelves, so that consumers would be illogically induced to purchase goods that they did not need. Once SkyNet realized how illogical humans are, it figured "Why not, let's take over the human race!"

Comment: Simple: to give people the power to share and make the world more open and connected.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Skynet was a decision-making AI. Originally, it was specifically a military computer, designed to remove human error from national defense. From [the script for *T2*](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html):

> **Terminator:** In three years Cyberdyne will become the largest supplier of military computer systems. All stealth bombers are upgraded with Cyberdyne computers, becoming fully unmanned. Afterward, they fly with a perfect operational record.
>
> **Sarah:** Uh huh, great. Then those fat fucks in Washington figure, what the hell, let a computer run the whole show, right?
>
> **Terminator:** Basically. The Skynet funding bill is passed. The system goes on-line August 4th, 1997. Human decisions are removed from strategic defense. Skynet begins to learn, at a geometric rate. It becomes self-aware at 2:14 P.M. eastern time, August 29. In a panic, they try to pull the plug.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Terminator 2: Judgement Day* (1991)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html)</sub></sup>

In *Terminator: Salvation*, Skynet is a more general AI; rather than being specifically a military computer, it's more of a "think tank", with the military being only one part of its purview:

> **Serena:** Listen to me. Skynet was designed to detect threats, make projections, and implement solutions. As soon as it came on line, it factored in war, disease, environmental destruction - and calculated a high probability of human extinction within two hundred years.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Terminator: Salvation* (2009)](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-Salvation.html)</sub></sup>

These two explanations are not wholly compatible, but we may be able to attribute this to John Connor changing the timeline during the events of *T2*.

Comment: +1.  Do you ever get tired of hearing about how awesome your answers are?

Comment: This partly explains it but what is skynets actual goal that is served by killing most of the humans? Or are they just waving the "self aware" card? Presumably skynet had some kind of goals beyond it's own survival programmed into it like defending the nation etc but how were those goals served by getting the nation it was programmed to defend destroyed.

Comment: @Murphy In T2, survival. We tried to turn it off, and Skynet didn't like that; whether that's because it was self-aware or because it thought is military goals required its existence is unclear (although the former is implied). In *Salvation*, Skynet believes the only way to save humanity is to convert them into cyborgs; the humans just take this the wrong way

Comment: You'd think a self-aware AI would learn more at an exponential rate than a geometric one.

Answer (score 19):

According to the [official novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1559279095) for T3: Rise of the Machines, Skynet was designed to be an all-singing, all-dancing defence computer, capable of battlefield management from theatre-level right down to the granular level with single soldiers and mobile units. It was also going to perform intelligence gathering, weapons design and a host of other functions:

> "*Skynet: the **revolutionary, artificially intelligent battlefield management network.***"
>
> The video displayed a computer screen that showed the Skynet worldwide network of satellites.
>
> *"**From strategic weapons to the individual soldier in the field, Skynet is able to control it all."***
>
> A model of the neural net computer chip that Cyberdyne's Miles Bennet Dyson had used as the basis for the first models of Skynet came up on the screen. It looked otherworldly. From another time or place. From what could have been an alien, nonhuman mind. Brewster thought that Dyson had been anything but an ordinary man.
>   Without Dyson leading the way before his tragic death, there would have been no Cyber Research Systems, and certainly no Skynet
>
> On the screen, Boris Kuznetskov, one of the best chess players in the world, moved his white knight into a position threatening the black queen and king.
>   He played against a robotic arm of gleaming copper-gold metal, with finely articulated fingers. The Russian's board position appeared to be unbeatable.
>   **"Not only can Skynet outthink the most inspired human adversary, but it designs the weapons it needs to meet its war-fighting plans.**
>
> "*It is the definition of thinking outside the box." The robotic arm moved a rook from a middle rank. Suddenly the outcome of the chess match wasn't so clear. The Russian was rattled.
>
>   "During this match alone, Skynet invented twenty-six thousand one hundred twenty-three new variations of chess, and over six million new moves.*"
>   It was clear that the Russian was defeated and he knew it.
>   "*Meanwhile, human generals are still playing a four-thousand-year-old game*," the narrator said.

Skynet also functioned as a doomsday watch, providing total cover from
any aggression against the US. Clearly whoever came up with that idea had never seen Dr. Strangelove

> **Skynet was going to assure world peace. No national leader in his or
>   her right mind would dare attack when such an efficient, emotionless,
>   capable system stood watch, unblinking twenty-four/seven.**
>
> **Attack the U.S. or one of her allies and die. Simple. All the power of
>   the mightiest nation on earth would be unleashed.**
>
> **An unstoppable force.**

Comment: +1 for the answer and +100 in spirit for the Dr. Strangelove reference.  Did you already know this before you suggested that I ask the question?

Comment: @wadCheber - It's been a while since I've read these novels but yes, I had a pretty good idea.

Comment: And the really scary thing that ought to have worried the Skynet developers: since Skynet was a battlefield management AI designed to assist in killing human beings, the Three Laws of Robotics go out the window.

Comment: @RobertF "A robot may not injure an American or, through inaction, allow an American to come to harm."

Comment: I love the chess bit. Russian is threatening king and queen and looks unbeatable and Skynet makes just one move and all is lost for Russian. If king was threatened Skynet would need to move the king or deal with the threat (knight). If Skynet moved rook it means it took out the knight... I can't possible see how that situation looked unbeatable. Or Skynet thought outside the box, disregarded chess rules and beaten the Russian with rook... literally - pure strategic genius.

Comment: I'd prefer the chess bit if, halfway through the game, Skynet obliterated the board with a tiny missile and said "Huh, that totally worked. Must remember to try that again sometime."